# Update only when I change selection

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an app which requires to change values when changing selectinputs. In the code given below the obserevent changes value automatically with the input expression. This should not be the case as there will be a default value at the beginning but changes its value only if I change selection.

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
         selectInput("Year", "Year", c(2016:2020)),

      # Setting a default value

         numericInput("num1", "Number",NA, value = 1234615, step = 1)
  )

 server <- function(input,output,session){

   # Update to value 56 only if I change year selection
   # In this case the value is automatically updated if we have input$Year but it 
   # should be only when I change the input$Year from the dropdown selectInput value 

   observeEvent(input$Year,{
       updateNumericInput(session,"num1","Number",value = 56, step = 1)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I hope the everyone reviewing this code get my point. Please help me to solve this as I am not able to find out a way to make the app to do this specific task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. What is your expected behavior? You always update `num1` if `Year` is changed. This functionality is quite clear, is'nt it?

Answer (score 1):

`observeEvent` has options such as `ignoreInit`, which is set to `FALSE` by default so change that to `TRUE` should be what you want

> observeEvent(eventExpr, handlerExpr, event.env = parent.frame(),
>   event.quoted = FALSE, handler.env = parent.frame(),   handler.quoted =
>   FALSE, label = NULL, suspended = FALSE,   priority = 0, domain =
>   getDefaultReactiveDomain(),   autoDestroy = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE,
>   ignoreInit = FALSE,   once = FALSE)

---

```
observeEvent(input$Year,{
    updateNumericInput(session,"num1","Number",value = 56, step = 1)
},ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

Comment: I again ran into the similar problem when using the observeEvent from the module server side even after using the  **ignoreInit = TRUE**. Can you explain me this differential behavior. I have added a separate post in stackoverflow: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024757/observeevent-issues-in-shiny-modules)