# ObserveEvent issues in shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny, module

Hoping the everyone is doing good in these tough times.

In my demo app the observeEvent when run from the module server side updates the numeric value instantly even when I am using **ignoreInit = TRUE** . This argument is working fine in Shiny apps without the shiny modules.
I ran into a this trivial problem while using observeEvent from module server which  I am not understanding why?  Can anyone explain the reason for such differential behavior in Shiny apps?

Below is my Demo code

```
       library(shiny)
       library(shinyjs)
      # Module UI

          ui_module <- function(id){
               ns <- NS(id)
                     fluidRow(
                           selectInput(ns("Year"),"Year",c(2020:2050)),
                           uiOutput(ns("Input_ui")),
             # Default value define in ui
                 tags$div(id = ns("Def_id") ,numericInput(ns("default"),"Deafault",NA,value = 
                             2423,step = 1))
                   )
           }

      # Module Server

              server_module <- function(input,output,session){

          # Default value while rendering ui.

            output$Input_ui <- renderUI({
                        ns <- session$ns
                       numericInput(ns("Input"), "Number", NA, value = 537153, step = 1)
            })

        # Values update anyhow at the start even if I am using ignoreInit = TRUE
        # The argument works in Apps without the shiny modules but not here. WHY???

               observeEvent(input$Year,{
                            updateNumericInput(session,
                                         "Input", "Number",value = 4, step = 1)

                            updateNumericInput(session,
                                          "default", "Deafault",value = 60, step = 1)},ignoreInit = TRUE)
                         }

         # App UI

                ui <- fluidPage(

                       inlineCSS(".row {margin:60px 0;}
                       div[id *= 'input_div']{position:absolute;left:26em;width:200px;height:30px;}
                       div[id *= 'input2_div']{position:absolute;left:20em;width:200px;height:30px;
                       div[id *= 'Def_id']{position:absolute;left:30em;width:200px;height:30px;"),

            fluidRow(id = "Row",
                      uiOutput("ui"),
                      actionButton("add","ADD")
                   )
              )

       # APP Server

                server <- function(input,output,session){

                   #Counter

                   n <- 0

         # One by one adding the modules

              observeEvent(input$add,{
                          n <<- n + 1
                          panels <- paste0("panels_new",n)
                           insertUI("#Row",
                           "beforeEnd",
                           ui_module(panels))

                 callModule(server_module,panels)
           })

              # Generating a no of shiny modules based on the some table rows
              # n will be nrow in my main app.

             output$ui <- renderUI({
                         n <- 2
                         list <- as.list(1:n)
                         lapply(list, function(i){
                         panels <- paste0("panels",i)
                                  fluidRow(
                                        ui_module(panels)
                                        )
                               }) 
                 })

             observe({
                      n <- 2
                     list <- as.list(1:n)
                     lapply(list, function(i){
                     panels <- paste0("panels",i)
                     callModule(server_module,panels)
                 })
            })
       }

    shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Thanks

Jitu

Comment: You have multiple `Year` arguments triggering similar to this question if you `print(input$Year)` you will see its doing it 2 times by default. So just create unique ones (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169876/observeevent-shiny-function-used-in-a-module-does-not-work

Comment: Ok I will check it then. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why it prints multiple times (in one case I found it to be printed thrice) from shiny modules whereas in normal shiny it prints only once?

Comment: The `input$Year` expression doesn't work well with observeEvent in Shiny module. So, replacing it with action button however does the job perfectly. But in my case I need to see change without clicking any button and default values changes only on year change. It seems that making a list of independent but similar input panels doesn't work with the input$Year exp which is not the case with a single input panels. I tried to observeEvent without involving the shiny modules by directly making a list of input panels in my App server but there also the results with input$Year is the same.

Comment: Anybody having any idea that why this particular behavior with the input panel list where the only  **eventExpr** working perfectly well is the action button and not any other expression like in my case input$Year.

Comment: The input$Year is printed twice but its length is always one, why this is so? Even when I  am using a unique function, it is still not working.